# WPF DataGrid Style Change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mahapps.metro

I have the following XAML for a custom `DataGrid`:

```
<Controls:ResourceDataGrid 
    x:Name="resourceDataGrid" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    Style="{StaticResource MetroDataGrid}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources, 
                          Mode=TwoWay,
                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                          IsAsync=True}" 
    ...
    AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Event="CellEditEnding"
    AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding DynamicColumnTargetChangedCommand}">
    ...
</Controls:ResourceDataGrid>
```

I am styling the control according to MahAppsMetro and the grid looks great. However, when I change the applications 'theme'/'accent' all windows change color and all MahAppsMetro controls also change **but** the `DataGrid` that I have detailed above does not.

The `DataGrid` is styled as a `MetroDataGrid`, so why isn't this control being updated, *and* what do I have to do to get it to update the 'theme'/'accent' color for this control?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you explain this line futher more: Style="{StaticResource MetroDataGrid}" ?

Comment: The `MetroDataGrid` is `StaticResource' which is loaded from the MahAppsMetro library... Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Themes only work on `CustomControl`s. In order to provide different 'skins' for controls, you need to have a `CustomControlLibrary` project with a XAML file named `generic.xaml`.

You can find a short basic description in the [Themes/generic.xaml](http://wangmo.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/themesgenericxaml/) page on Martins' 10 blog, or if you prefer more depth, you can find a complete description in the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sheridan. I will take a detailed look at the references shortly. Because I am styling the control according to a referenced library, the fact that the controls style is indeed being adopted from said library, I assumed that any changed in style for the underlying library should also change my control?

Comment: You have written your own implementation of a `DataGrid` that is just using a `Style` from the `MahAppsMetro.dll`. `Style`s are not updated when changing 'skins', instead a different `Style` is used. However, all of this only happens because that `DataGrid` has registered it's name/type and `Style`s in `generic.xaml` whereas you have not registered yours. That is something that is done when you define a `CustomControl`.